# opening file of registered file type in phonegap / cordova app in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'd like to open a specific file type (e.g. from email client) in my cordova app on iOS.

Looking at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) documentation  and this nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)  I can learn how can I read the content of the file in  iOS app, but I need to manipulate the data in my javascript code.

Can anyone give me a hint how to pass the imported data into cordova app?

Comment: have you tried using the xmlhttprequest to read the file?

Comment: @thst no I haven't can you give me a sample?

Comment: https://github.com/poja/PhoneGap-FileAPI-Improved here is an api for files, based on the original phonegap code. if you search for "phonegap file api", you will find some articles.

Comment: @thst thanks, but to me it looks like a sandboxed filesystem, how can I open the file which came via email?

Comment: I think, this covers what you are looking for? The iOS way is to open the app handling the file from the email app. https://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/handling-phonegap-ios-application-using-custom-url-scheme/

Comment: The mindfiremobile link covers a different case: registering a custom URL protocol/prefix. The question here: how to register a file type (UTI?), as asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559991/cordova-register-file-types-to-open-with-list but with no answer.