# Cordova register file types to 'open with' list

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I'd like to register my Ionic app (through Cordova) to open certain file types. Just like Dropbox does. When a user has a file on another application (like email), and he clicks 'open with', there's a list which contains the Dropbox app.

Heres a tutorial from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Is there any Cordova plugin that support both Android and iOS and gives a JS API to that feature? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve FileType association in Cordova.

It includes 2 steps.

1) register files in Android Manifest / iOS plist as

Manifest

```
<intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_launcher'
        android:label='AndroidMHT File'
    android:priority='1'>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" /> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="*.mht" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.mht" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.mht" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822" android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:mimeType="multipart/related" android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822" android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:mimeType="multipart/related" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Document-molecules-320.png</string>
            <string>Document-molecules-64.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Molecules Structure File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.sunsetlakesoftware.molecules.pdb</string>
            <string>org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

2) Use the [File Opener Plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

You may need to pass necessary flags to open those files.

Reference: [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903443/android-file-associations), [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) and a [phonegap community forum thread](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/associate_a_phonegapp_app_with_a_file_type)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links (I fixed the Android one). I haven't had a chance to test, but it seems like the right approach. An actual plug-in would be easier (like registering a URL scheme), but I think I can use a hook to have the plist changes done by a script.

AFAIK, the 'File Opener Plugin' is NOT relevant, i.e. it would let my app tell the OS to open someone else's file, whereas this question is only about making sure another app (like email) can send the file to my app.

Comment: Hi,
How can I get the file address on the webapp itself? (a user pressed open with on a photo, and now he is being transferred to my app, what's next?)

Comment: Anyone has been able to find the next step to grab the file? @DanielGolub ?

Comment: Hi, has someone found a complete solution to this? Can you please post links?

Answer (score 1):

check this [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event).
Regarding Let'sRefactor its is correct except for fileopener , in the intent you should identify what function to call ( in native of-course ) when a user open file with your app.
It is all explained in the link above.